# How can I get Firefox to attach an XML namespace to my html element?

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-browser, xhtml

I'm creating XHTML documents client-side as follows:

```
var xhtmlDocType = document.implementation.createDocumentType(
  'html',
  '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN',
  'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'
);
myDocument = document.implementation.createDocument('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'html', xhtmlDocType);
```

When running this code in Chrome, the output (`myDocument.documentElement.outerHTML`) is as I expect, and the resulting html element looks like this: `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`, however when running the same code in Firefox, the html element has no xmlns attribute: `<html>`. The Firefox document also seems to be treated as HTML, doing things like not closing `<meta>` tags.

Here's a JSFiddle to serve an an example, which can be viewed in Chrome or Firefox to see the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/70avhuo3/5/

In my particular use case, I need that xmlns attribute, and Firefox to treat the document as XHTML in order for the document to both be valid and display properly.  How can I get consistency here, either by modifying the way I create the document, or how I am extracting the contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox *is* treating the document as an XMLDocument, not an HTML document. You can tell this because if you get an element's `tagName`, if it's an HTML document, the tagName will be in upper case, even if you specify `createElement()` in lower case. That doesn't happen in an XMLDocument.

See http://jsfiddle.net/70avhuo3/6/ as opposed to http://jsfiddle.net/70avhuo3/7/

You're not seeing the xmlns attribute because of the implementation of `outerHTML`. For an XML document, this should, according to the [DOM serialization and parsing draft spec](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/innerhtml/raw-file/tip/index.html#dfn-concept-fragment-serializing-algorithm), serialize the DOM to XML, but it seems Firefox doesn't do that.

You can use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(myDocument.documentElement);` instead, to get an XML serialization in Firefox. See http://jsfiddle.net/70avhuo3/8/

---

By the way, I strongly encourage you to always use `createElementNS()` with XMLDocuments, never `createElement()`. In DOM3 `createElement()` will put the element in the null namespace, while the DOM4 spec currently says that it will go in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace, though the change remains an issue of active debate.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the attribute directly? It *appears* to work as expected in Firefox.

```
myDocument.documentElement.setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml')
```

Comment: Sorry, I need to edit my question for clarification.  That does set the attribute, but Firefox still doesn't treat the document as XHTML (not closing meta tags, for example).

Comment: I did wonder if it was superficial. I haven't had to deal with xhtml in a while!